# Traceback on syntax when trying to define normal operator functions in Python

Tags: python

The goal of my code is to define a function that will allow me to enter  `+` `-` `*` or `/` and then 2 values, and have the function evaluate the supplied numbers

```
def basic_op(operator, value1, value2):
    try:    
        operator = input('Choose operator: +, -, * or /')
        value1 = int(input('Value1:'))
        value2 = int(input('Value2:'))
            if operator == '+'
                return(value1 + value2)
            elif operator == '-'
                return(value1 - value2)
            elif operator == '*'
                return(value1 * value2)
            else: operator == '/'
                return(int(value1 / value2))
     except:
         print("Invalid value entered")
```

I have a syntax error at the end of the lines for the if/elif/else, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Correct indentation is critical in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Correct indentation is very important in python.
so you should do this.(don't indent if-statement)

```
def basic_op(operator, value1, value2):
    try:    
        operator = input('Choose operator: +, -, * or /')
        value1 = int(input('Value1:'))
        value2 = int(input('Value2:'))
        if operator == '+'
            return(value1 + value2)
        elif operator == '-'
            return(value1 - value2)
        elif operator == '*'
            return(value1 * value2)
        else: operator == '/'
            return(int(value1 / value2))
     except:
         print("Invalid value entered")
```